# Automatic tableView cell size in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, tableview

I want to make a `UITableView` which automatically adjust it's cell size by it's contents.

The contents are from XML file and the data is just text.

I want to put the text in a `cell` and it should be automatically does `word-wrap` and support multi-line.

So each cell can have different height. Is this possible?? or any idea?

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. Make use of the following method for doing it,

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath    {
CGSize cellHeight;
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cellHeight = [yourXMLContents sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(300.0, 1000.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return cellHeight.height + 20;
}  else 
    return  30;
```

}

Comment: I tried this but for some reason the return value from heightForRowAtIndexPath method is over 50, but the cell size is always 46 in cellForRowAtIndexPath method. Why is that? heightForRowAtIndexPath is called first, and then cellForRowAtIndexPath is called.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [three20 library](https://github.com/facebook/three20)? It'll resize the cells to fit the content. In the very least, you can look at how the code is implemented to resize cells.

Comment: thanks I've never heard of three20. But now I can at least look at it how it does. BTW are you Korean?

Comment: glad to see korean in StackOverflow ;)